# What is "Introspection-based code completion"?

Tags: python, ide

I'm looking at various IDEs for python. Looking at the official [list](http://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments) the IDEs are categorized based on '**introspection based code completion**'.

What does introspection based code completion mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means the IDE uses introspection to figure out what methods and variables are accessible from a given object, then allows quick code completion, usually by providing a list of options after you type a period following a symbol.

Comment: And it also usually means that the introspection is based on the actual scoping rules, so it will look closely enough at your code to figure out, what you could possibly do, without showing you inaccessible names (variables, methods) etc.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example if WingIDE Pro inaction. Forgive the hastily thrown together image.

[image: This is the image]

You can see that `arg1` is being shown as `1` in the first example, as well as the helper showing that it is probably an `int`.

In the second part, you can see that the IDE is looking through the docstrings for what the method `get` does, in the `requests` module.

The second image below shows that the IDE can 'auto-complete' code for you, including showing what it does. [image]